# How to import libstreaming in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

I am a old developer with Eclipse IDE now I switched to Android Studio. I want to use the below tutorial

[Live Stream Library](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/http://)

I want to import the libstreaming library to Android Studio.

[libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming)

Comment: Have you included "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')" in your gladle file?

Comment: Its a complete eclipse project. I think the thing you have provided is for jar files

Comment: hey saty, did you get any solution for your problem? i am also stuck in same issue from past few days. pls help

Answer (score 8):

With the help of [Fritte's comment on this page](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/issues/153), I did the following to import libstreaming into my Android Studio (v1.5.1) project:

- Create a new Android Project
- Clone `libstreaming` into an other directory
- In your new Android Project, File > New > Import Module > `Path to libstreaming`

You can then add libstreaming as a dependency in your app by adding `compile project(':libstreaming')` to the dependencies section of your build.gradle (Module:app) file. E.g., mine now looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile project(':libstreaming')
}
```

Comment: Hi I did the steps above but it did not work RtspClient, Session, SurfaceView or marked as red

Comment: You need to add libstreaming as module dependency as well. Project Structures -> Dependencies -> select your module (mine is app, your might be the same) -> click + -> Module dependency -> select libstreaming

Comment: is this library still applicable for the latest android version support?