# IDE Error when importing library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import, nullpointerexception, ide

I want to import [this library](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) into my Android Project in Android Studio.
[I tried to do it this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539445/how-to-import-libstreaming-in-android-studio)

So I cloned the library and did `File > New > Import Module > Path to libstreaming`
but i get an IDE Fatal Error:

```
Exception in Plugin Android

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.GradleImport.getBuildToolsVersion(GradleImport.java:1081)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.GradleImport.createModuleBuildGradle(GradleImport.java:971)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.GradleImport.exportModule(GradleImport.java:927)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.GradleImport.exportProject(GradleImport.java:792)
```

I am using Android Studio Version 2021.1.1 Patch 1.

I dont know what to do with this Exception...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a clone of this library compile it and then add the jar under libs. But beware this library has not been updated in years.